# How correctly use Store (flow) in Android Kotlin multiplatform

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-flow

how correctly use flow from library [Store](https://github.com/MobileNativeFoundation/Store) in **Android - Kotlin Multiplatform** project.

I cant find way how to use only flow - to get search data ...  if I collect data in Compose like this ... UI isnt update and not call new request for refresh data ...

```
val data by viewModel.searchMovieFlow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(
       initialValue = StoreResponse.Loading()
    )
```

So I published the repository "*example*" with that in **ViewModel** I collect **flow** and "transform" to **LiveData** and this is working ...
https://github.com/LeopoldPodmolik/example-kmm-films

Thank you for any advice.